# Get all values from async statements

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have a 3 function:

First just returns the value

Second calls a setTimeout

Third returns promise with the value

**I can't touch these 3 functions.**

Here they are:

```
const A = "A";
const B = "B";
const C = "C";

function getA() {
  return A;
}

function getB(callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback(B);
  }, 10);
}

function getC() {
  return Promise.resolve().then(() => C);
}
```

I need to create a function which will return the output of all three function in the array with promise.

So far I tried this:

```
function getABC() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let a = getA();
    let b = getB(B => B);
    let c = getC().then(() => C);
    let arr = [a, b, c];
    resolve(arr);
  }).then((arr) => arr);
}

getABC().then((arr) => console.log(arr));
```

It should return `['A', 'B', 'C']` but instead it returns `['A', undefined, Promise {<pending>}]`;

I tried different approaches but they were all false.

Comment: Your `getB()` function has no return value.

Comment: @Pointy sorry I forgot to mention that I can;t touch these 3 functions, is there a way to do it without changing the getA, getB and getC function? Thank you

Comment: You only need to promisify getB, then use Promise.all

Comment: side note: `.then((arr) => arr)` does nothing, and might as well be removed

Comment: @rksh1997 that's interesting, but can you help me with code please. I don't know how to realise that in the right way.

Comment: Here's an already written answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22519785/11215806

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way of doing it:

```js
const A = "A";
const B = "B";
const C = "C";

function getA() {
  return A;
}

function getB(callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback(B);
  }, 10);
}

function getC() {
  return Promise.resolve().then(() => C);
}

function getABC() {
  // This is used to extract the value from the function getB
  const obj = {};
  const cb = (b) => obj.b = b;
 
  getB(cb);
  // The callback cb will be called only in 10ms, that why there is a
  // timeout here to wait that the value b is extracted
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(getC().then(c => [getA(), obj.b, c])), 10);
  });
}

// Another way: wrap the function getB and then use Promise.all
function getABC2() {
  function wrapGetB() {
    const obj = {};
    const cb = (b) => obj.b = b;
    getB(cb);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(obj.b), 10);
    });
  }

  return Promise.all([getA(), wrapGetB(), getC()]);
}

getABC().then((arr) => console.log(arr));
getABC2().then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way seems to be add this to the original code, as suggested by @rksh1997 above

```
Promise.all([
    getA(),
    new Promise(getB), // callback == 'resolve()'
    getC(),
]).then(console.log);
```